# Can I get MarkdownRemark nodes at onCreateNode()?

Tags: gatsby

I tried to get MarkdownRemark nodes at onCreateNode() like this.

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ getNodesByType, node }) => {
    if (node.internal.type === 'Directory') {
        const markdowns = getNodesByType('MarkdownRemark');

        console.log(markdowns); // empty array
    }
};
```

I guess when I access to markdown files, the markdown nodes haven't been created yet, because directory nodes are created first.

Is there any way to access to markdown nodes? Thank you for your reply in advance!

---

That's my gatsby-config.js :)

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: { title:'site' },
    plugins: [
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
            options: {
                name: 'gatsby-starter-default',
                short_name: 'starter',
                start_url: '/',
                background_color: '#663399',
                theme_color: '#663399',
                display: 'minimal-ui',
                icon: 'src/images/gatsby-icon.png'
            },
        },
        'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
        'gatsby-plugin-typescript',
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-linaria',
            options: {
                preprocessor: 'none',
                sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : true
            },
        },
        'gatsby-plugin-sass',
        'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
            options: {
                name: 'images',
                path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
            options: {
                name: 'posts',
                path: `${__dirname}/src/posts`,
            },
        },
        'gatsby-transformer-remark',
        'gatsby-transformer-sharp'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: I've added contents of gatsby-config.js :D Thanks @ksav

Comment: What happens if you move `'gatsby-transformer-remark'` higher up in your plugins array?

Comment: It's still not working. I have tried to move plugin's position many times last night. but it failed :’ I think I should access to directory nodes the other way around when markdown nodes are created. Thanks !